# Handling Activity Stack in Android, am I leaking Memory with My approach.?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 4 Different Activities, and going through the links I have created a Sample for the same.

`Objective:`

`Activities A,B,C,D;`

`A -> B -> C -> D`

An event in D causes `C` and `D` to pop Leaving `A and B` in stack.

An event in D may cause `B` `C` and `D` to POP leaving only `A` in stack.

`Implementation:`

I use the following Event for my First Three Activities i.e. `A B C`

```
if(v==buttonNext){
        Intent secondAct=new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        //storing the Stack
         MaintainMyStack.addBackActivity(this); 
        startActivity(secondAct);
    }
```

I use the following Event for my Forth Act. i.e. `D`

```
if(v==btnBack){
        finish();//finishes  "D"
        Activity act=MaintainMyStack.getBackActivity();

        act.finish(); //finishes last in stack i.e. "C"
    }
```

I use this Common Class Amongst My `A B C D` Activities.

```
public class MaintainMyStack  {
    private static Stack<Activity> classes = new Stack<Activity>();

    public static Activity getBackActivity() {
    return classes.pop();
    }
    public static void addBackActivity(Activity c) {
    classes.push(c);
    }
}
```

It works as desired, but I am just concerned about the `MaintainMyStack` class might Leak Memory when it meets real Scenerio, Please suggest should I go with this approach or Do we have other options to implement the same.
How can i create the `MaintainMyStack` have just one instance without leaking any memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the `Intents` flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP). Adding this flag to your `Intent` will do exactly what you are trying to achieve with your own activity stack, and you won't need that anymore.

Comment: Yes Ovidiu, I understand this approach, and it seems to work perfectly fine with my current requirements, Just one more query with your approach, does it call the whole Activity again (creates a new one) or is it the same activity from the Display Stack?

Comment: Because I believe your approach won't save the initialized values, and would re-initialize all again, as it calls `onCreate()`

Comment: make your A and B as singleTask in manifest, thus would not re-initialze A and B again, their onNewIntent() will be called

Comment: Yes, Achieved exactly what i wanted to, will you please make this as your Answer so that I can Accept it. !!

Answer (score 1):

If you use this then no need to maintain you stack yourself.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FourthActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
FourthActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

You can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP but sometimes it wont work.Sometimes it pops only top activity.

Comment: Anyways your approch is good for maintaining stack. If you have done with it can you give its implementation of MaintainMyStack class.